# Is there a library to remove HTML tags in Ballerina?

Tags: ballerina

I am trying to build a scan report parser. As a parsing step, I need to remove HTML tags from some of the fields in the report.

I have tried to find a Ballerina library that can be used to remove HTML tags, but could not find any.

Answer (score -1):

We can use Ballerina regular expressions to filter out HTML tags. The below code demonstrates its use for your purpose:

```
import ballerina/io;
import ballerina/lang.regexp;
import ballerina/lang.'string;

public function main() {
    string:RegExp r = re `<[/]*[a-zA-Z0-9]+>`;

    string htmlDoc = string `
        <html>
            <head>
                <title>Sample "Hello, World" Application</title>
            </head>
            <body>
                <p>Hello, World</p>
            </body>
        </html>
    `;

    string result = regexp:replaceAll(r, htmlDoc, "");
    io:println(result);
}
```

Comment: [You shouldn't use regex to parse/strip HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags?noredirect=1&lq=1&answertab=scoredesc#tab-top)

Comment: I think you should just teat HTML as XML and use xml functionality in Ballerina to manipulate it as you wish.